# Not able to add class library dll to Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I can’t see the unblock button and the same means its already unblock to use,right! but i’m not able to add the class library reference to my Windows Phone 8 application and error ‘A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project’ appears. Please help me out!

Comment: Is your class library a Windows Phone assembly?

Comment: no I have added Windows Class Library.

Comment: Windows Phone projects are not compatible with Windows Class Libraries.

Comment: ok! After googling a lot now I added a PortableClassLibrary but I'm not getting my required namespaces- System.Data,System.Web.Services etc. Please help me out.

Comment: And if you try to create a Windows Phone library? (not a portableClassLibrary)

Comment: Yes I tried to create a Windows Phone library but my required namespace were not available.

Comment: I tried to create a Windows Phone library but I'm not getting my required namespaces- System.Data,System.Web.Services etc. Please help me out.

Comment: When you created a portable class library did you specify Windows Phone projects? The namespaces you are after are likely not present in Windows Phone